# Cordova Android - selecting textarea clears radio buttons

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am having a strange issue with textareas and radio buttons on my cordova android application.

I have a radio button and a textarea on my page. When I select the radio button, then go to select the textarea, the radio button becomes unchecked.

I have tested this on the browser and it works as expected (it doesn't uncheck the radio button), same applied with my iOS version of the application.

I don't have any javascript or anything running to make this happen so I have hit a dead end so far.

Has anyone came across this before?

I am running cordova 4.1.1 on Android 6.0.

**UPDATE:**

This only seems to happen when the keyboard shows and hides. If i select the textarea, the click the radio button, it briefly checks the radio button, the keyboard hides then it becomes unchecked again.

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: yeap mate some code would help a lot